# Does the Trailing Return include Expense Ratio fee?

Tags: investing, etf, yahoo-finance

In Yahoo Finance, If I look at the 5-Year Trailing Return for an ETF - does it include the Expense Ratio fee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Trailing return is based on historical Price, and Total Expense Ratio is taken out of the Price daily.